# Change navigation active class on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a scroll effect like here  http://www.strikingly.com/s/pages/default-ion?demo=ion#1
All i need for this moment is to change navigation li class active when the window is scrolling , just change the it using `<a href='#about'>` hash target

http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/131/

Comment: here is a good reference which i found.[here](https://github.com/trungk18/Change-Navigation-Active-Class-on-Page-Scroll.git)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

[Serlite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387174/serlite)'s code is very good but had some bugs.

1. If you scroll down to the end last two `a` elements have `active` class so both are highlighted.

**Solution**

added `$('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");` to remove all previous active class before adding new class in the below code.

```
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active"); //added to remove active class from all a elements
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

2. If you click on 2nd or greater menu link it makes you scroll to the location but changes active class to previous link.

**Solution**

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helps my, it is exactly what i wanted

Comment: I used this script and i think it is exactly what i want. I don't get it to work. If i scroll it gives an error on each link i want to scroll. This is the error: [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refElement.position().top')

Comment: @TusharGupta this is what i'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/5826xLmp/ I have got it to work and it was a really dumb mistake. i use it in wordpress and wordpress uses jquery 1.11.1 and if i forced wordpress to use 1.9.1 and is all works now.

Comment: @andredewaard great, you fixed the issue :)

Comment: This code doesn't work as I have expected when parent of the refElement has `position: relative`. The fix is simple, use offset() insted of position().


`if (refElement.offset().top <= scrollPos && refElement.offset().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {`

Comment: Hello @TusharGupta-curioustushar - I'm really sorry to bother you, but could you take a quick look at my most recent question regarding this topic. You'll probably be able to fix it easily (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414249/make-the-change-of-active-class-in-the-menu-more-reliable-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 5):

Well...not sure if you're still looking for an answer to your question, but I can contribute a suggestion...

As mentioned, you could use the `scrollTop()` method to determine what section is presently in the viewport. Here's a quick function I threw together to determine this, it may not be optimized (I'm not a jQuery expert, sorry), but it seems to work, and should at least put you on the right path to a solution:

```
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

This function basically takes the `href` of each menu anchor element, and uses it to find the `<div>` (or any other element, if you like) with a matching id in the document. After this, it checks to see whether the top of that `<div>` is above or at the current scroll position, and its bottom is still below the current scroll position. (Those two conditions being true means that this `<div>` is the one currently highest in the viewport, and so should be considered the active section.) The class `.active` is then removed/added accordingly. Of course, you can just add/subtract values if you want to offset when a section is considered "active".

Maybe it's easier just showing what it does, so here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/140/) with this function implemented. It's initially bound using `$(document).on("scroll")` - however, note that I also unbound it from the scroll event using `$(document).off("scroll")` while the smooth scrolling occurs, so that the section doesn't change until you've reached the destination section (if you click on one of the menu links). After the smooth scrolling occurs, I bind the function again to the scroll event.

Anyways, I hope this is what you were looking for! If it's not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. (Or I'll try, at least - since as I mentioned, jQuery isn't really my specialty...) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helps my, cool code, it is exactly what i wanted

Comment: Aha! I only tested this in the (approximately) latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. But you're right, it does have a hiccup in IE9 (at the very least). Anyways, glad the question got fully answered either way!

Comment: I want to use this script and i think it is exactly what i want only I don't get it to work. If i scroll it gives an error on each link i want to scroll. This is the error: [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refElement.position().top')

Comment: It sounds a bit like the value stored to refElement may be incorrect. Do you have your full implementation online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).scrollTop();` on your event listener to check what section is in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

hiccup in IE9 so I corrected

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-48}, 500);
    return false;

        $("#menu a").click(function () {
            $("#menu a").removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $(target).offset().top-50}, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    j$('#menu a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top-70 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top-50 + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
           $('#menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but my answer may help the new viewers of this thread. Tushar Gupta's answer is correct. But if there a link in menu that is redirecting to any other page. Tushar Gupta's Answer will throw an error. For Example

```
    <div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a  href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a  href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a  href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a  href="http://mywebsite.com/blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a  href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="home"></div>
   <div id="portfolio"></div>
   <div id="about"></div>
   <div id="contact"></div>
```

This will throw an error in console like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/2961/). And scrolling will not work for Contact. I Updated Tushar's code to fix that issue.

```
function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#menu-center a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active"); //added to remove active class from all a elements
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
}
```