# Questions regarding changing active navigation item while scrolling with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am completely new to Javascript and have been having trouble following the answers in this thread: [Change navigation active class on window scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252374/change-navigation-active-class-on-window-scroll)

I edited the jsFiddle example with the classes of my navigation bar, and got that to work, but when I try to bring the script over to my actual website, it doesn't work anymore.  Perhaps it has something to do with the "currLink" variable?  I see that in the example they used the class "active" on the link, but in my site, which is based on Bootstrap, the active class is added to the list item tag.

Regardless, I have been unable to get it working, I was wondering if I'm overlooking something obvious.

Here is the HTML for my navbar:

```
<div id="navigation-bar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#top">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#philosophy">philosophy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#yoga_works">yoga works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#signup">start your journey</a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers">careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the Javascript I'm attempting to use:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>/ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

      //smoothscroll
      $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(document).off("scroll");

          $('a').each(function () {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          })
          $(this).addClass('active');

          var target = this.hash,
              wrap = target;
          $target = $(target);
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
              'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
          }, 500, 'swing', function () {
              window.location.hash = target;
              $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
          });
      });
  });

  function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('#navigation-bar a').each(function () {
          var currLink = $(this);
          var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
          if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
              currLink.addClass("active");
          }
          else{
              currLink.removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  }
  });

  </script>
```

Obviously I need to learn Javascript so I can troubleshoot basic things like this on my own, but in the meantime, I need to finish this project.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: ScrollSpy does this already. Check out the GetBootstrap docs on that. This is a much easier solution too, if you don't use ScrollSpy: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/  From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative

Comment: Thanks!  I completely overlooked how well-integrated ScrollSpy is with Bootstrap.