# OnePage Navigation - Active Indicator while scrolling with one excluded element?

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, scrolltop

I want to make a scroll effect, so that the website changes the `<a href="#" class="active"></a>` to the right link while scrolling. (Example: http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/7-single-page-smooth-scroll/)

However I want to exclude one element, which refers to another website (Actually it is a dropdown with some external links). In the following jsfiddle the problem shows up. The point "Exclude" should just be skipped and not mentioned by the script. Is there any easy solution for that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/332/

---

Source of jsfiddle: 
[Change navigation active class on window scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252374/change-navigation-active-class-on-window-scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check this Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/333/)

If you do not want that external link then why you not remove "Exclude" link, Remove this HTML from your existing Code,

```
<li><a href="#exclude" class="exclude">Exclude</a>
</li>
```

---

### Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/334/)

HTML

```
<div id="exclude"></div>
```

CSS

```
#exclude {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I want that the "Exclude" link stays in the HTML. The content of it isn't in the OnePager, though it should still stay in the navigation.

Comment: you want to set page content on that page ?

Comment: Hi user1153551, sorry for the misunderstanding. The structe of the HTML and CSS is just fine. 
The Exclude-link has some content on an exclude.php, but not on the index.php. However it has to stay in the navigation. So I guess there is something wrong with ths javascript. The script should highlight Home, Portfolio, About and Contact when scrolled there. So "Exclude" has to be skipped in the script, so that it doesnt influence it - but I dont know how to.

Comment: Exclude not skip in Script but your code not `<div id="exclude"></div>` missing thats why not work but now it perfect work. hope you give me plus credit and accept my answer.

Comment: I know  why it isn't working atm, anyway it is a very dirty solution with just adding a <div id="exclude"></div> to the content. I searched for a better JS. Anyway I just accepted your solution.