# jQuery Error while navigation scrolling

Tags: jquery, wordpress, error-handling

I'm using this page scroll "plugin" (https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/) for my WordPress website. It works perfect at the frontend, but at my console I get an error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jquery.js
```

How can I solve this problem? Does anyone have an idea?

I also tried to use jQuery version 1.9.1 and remove the other js, but the error still exists.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: I changed the jQuery Version to 1.9.1, but this didn't help. I also tried to deactivate all other javascript, but the error was still there...

Comment: Please add these details to your question. Then add the Code where you load the javascript(s). But there should be a line; # in the console, that will point you to where the problem originated.

Comment: All javascripts are embeded in my functions.php with the action wp_enqueue_scripts.

The error exists in jquery.js:2:12733

Comment: Okay I found something new:
On my website there are only two pages: index page and imprint. If I delete the imprint page the error on the index page disappears.

On the imprint page there aren't these section which should be trigged by the menu.

I also tried to embed the js only on the index page, but this didn't help..

Comment: Found a solution from @Arun:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252374/change-navigation-active-class-on-window-scroll