# Smooth centering of active element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add **smooth** centering of active element for horizontal navigation from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252374/change-navigation-active-class-on-window-scroll) .

So I used *scrollIntoView*, and it works.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.active'); el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center"});
```

But it centering active element only after I stop scrolling. Is it possible to centering element during scrolling?

If I use  *behavior: "auto"*, it centering element during scrolling. It works correctly. But I would like to have smooth centering.

There is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9euthrb8/

Comment: I guess you'll need to use keyframes/transform: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Thanks for advice. But there is no problem with animation, so I think that is not right way. Problem is that smooth animation works ONLY after end of scrolling. It seems that is problem with code execution, because if I set behavior: "auto", it works correctly. But if is behavior: "smooth", it seems like script is waiting for end of scroolling. But maybe I'm wrong. It is strange.